# What is the best strategy for a Deadringer and a "Your Eternal Reward" spy on 2Fort?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

So here is the scenario, I'm a spy on 2Fort and the match starts. My load out is the Deadringer with Your Eternal Reward.

When I try to get past enemy lines undisguised (I have eternal reward), but I always get shot up, even if I cloak and keep on going, making it extremely frustrating for me. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In general as the Spy, I've found it better to hang back in the initial 10 seconds of a round, or use an alternative exit from spawn, so that your (highly visible) teammates don't accidentally use you as an invisible meat shield. Failing that, make use of crouch, and follow behind an ubered heavy/medic combo. When your dead ringer activates, run sideways first, then forward, away from the rest of your teammates to draw less fire.

Comment: I don't know if this question is valid enough.  Having a "how should I use x with y " is typically very opinionated, as there are different playstyles depending on each person. That said, regarding the question, the dead ringer works horribly with the YER, imo

Comment: it used to be epic when the FEZ set gave the sound reduction, but now they removed it, so an enemy can hear you if you try to appear behind them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem you're facing is that you're playing 2Fort and using a setup that doesn't work well on that map. Basically using any different watch or knife would help you get past enemies immensely easier. 2Fort is not a spy friendly map but since you asked....

Without a disguise in the rather claustrophobic map you will be killed quickly so try to get into the water to enter their base. You won't find a lot of safe DR decloak spots near their spawns. The YER works on the idea that the first stab is the hardest to get but gets easier once you have the disguise. Look for a player with his back turned in the doors near the ground level.

Alternatively stand in the corner by the enemies doors on the ground level. When an enemy drops down from above from their spawn you may be able to get a quick stab.

Just to repeat: 2Fort sucks for spies. Going DR and/or YER in 2Fort makes it harder for yourself. Switch up the watches/knives

Comment: If you DO inisist on using YER though, head for the battlements.  Snipers on deck are an easy disguise, but even without them, you can hide in the corner next to the second spawn and wait for someone to come out.